# difference of reference plane/Plane Height / Z factor in Surface volume calculation?

Tags: arcgis-10.1, elevation, 3d-analyst, tin, volume

I have a TIN surface with Minimum elevation 25 m and Maximum elevation 140 m.
I want to calculate surface volume in different elevation between 25 and 140 meter. 
I wonder for example If I want to measure the area above 25 m ( which is the lowest elevation)
how shall I set the Plane Height and Z factor?

PS: I am working in Arcmap 10.1 area.

Answer (score 1):

z factor is used for the conversion between Z unit and XY unit. So if your coordiante system is in meter and your height too, z factor is 1. (it would be different if you have feet and meters, or degrees and meter etc)

For the plane height, all volume above (or below) this height will be measured. So in your case you will use 25 m

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Then it means I should not change z factor for measuring surface volume? The option that has to change is Plane height ? Am I right?

Comment: yes, that's it!